# jQuery clockInput: Disable Clock Time Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using `jQuery clockInput: Clock Time Picker` what i want that in some cases i do not need to set time, so in that case i want to disable time selection and set by default time which i set.

Here are the link which i use `https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clock-Time-Input-Plugin-jQuery-clockInput.html`

A simple code for the clock :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type=time]").clockInput(false);
});
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option for this **[plugin](https://github.com/shengslogar/jQuery.clockInput)**, It mean the author didn't provide an option to make it `disable` but you can do it on your own by a simple `css` property. Just set `data-disabled="disabled"` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=time]").clockInput(false);
});
```

```css
input[data-disabled="disabled"]+.jq-ci {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clock-Time-Input-Plugin-jQuery-clockInput/jquery.clockinput.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clock-Time-Input-Plugin-jQuery-clockInput/jquery.clockinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="time" data-disabled="disabled" value="14:30:00" />
```

Comment: thanks it works.!! Is there any solution to set time bydefault via database?

Comment: @Javed Glad to help. Yes, you can set value by default by `value="14:30:00"`

Comment: gt it is there any changes on css ?

Comment: @Javed setting default time? no it's not related to `css`